# VBScript redirect remote exe output to local system

Tags: redirect, vbscript, cmd, remote-server, wbem

I am using vbscript to run an exe on a remote system. First i connect to the remote system.

```
Set objSWbemServices = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer _
    (strComputer, "root\cimv2", _
    strUser, strPassword)
```

Then i create a process on the remote system.

```
Set Process = objSWbemServices.Get("Win32_Process")
result = Process.Create("cmd /C ""cd " & somedir & " && " & "Collector.exe -v", , , intProcessID)
```

Now this code works fine. **However the exe gives some output on the console which i want to redirect to a file on my local system**.

I tried the following options

```
result = Process.Create("cmd &1>abc.txt /C ""cd " & somedir & " && " & "Collector.exe -v", , , intProcessID)
```

While the above option does not work at all,

or

```
result = Process.Create("cmd /C ""cd " & somedir & " && " & "Collector.exe -v > abc.txt", , , intProcessID)
```

this code created the file in the remote system. However i want the file to be created in the local system from where i am running my vbscript. Any help??

Answer (score 1):

You could try redirecting the output to a UNC path:

```
Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

result = Process.Create("cmd /C ""cd " & somedir & " && " _
         & "Collector.exe -v > \\" & net.ComputerName & "\share\abc.txt" _
         , , , intProcessID)
```

The share must exist on the local computer and the user running the remote process must be granted write access to it.

Untested, though, so I'm not sure it'll work.